# Git error, "unknown option '--short'" - "command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: git, npm, installation, yarnpkg

I tried to do a fresh install of a package.json and got the following error:

[image: Screenshot]

Sadly, I do not quite understand the error message and googling the issue also did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a quite aged Git version which doesn't support `--short` as a [`rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) option.

Check your Git version with `git --version`.

Comment: thank you for your answer! updated to the newest version but still getting the same error